# pgAdmin4 SCRAM authentication libpq 10

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, libpq

First of all - I'm not an expert (to say the least).
I want to set up a PostgreSQL database on my Raspberry Pi 4, with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS and pgAdmin4, but I got stuck.

After running pgadmin in Python Virtual Environment and going to 127.0.0.1:5050, login page appears, all seems fine, until I try to set up a new server. After providing server name and address alert appears: "Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above"

Modifying `password-encryption` and `METHOD` in `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` to `md5` did not help.

Postgres 14, pgAdmin 4 v 6.10, libpq-dev is already the newest version (14.4-1.pgdg22.04+1).

Any suggestions?

Comment: All I can say is that *somewhere* on your machine is an old `libpq.so` which is used, probably by mistake. Try removing that file.

Comment: Changing password-encryption doesn't do anything by itself.  You have to reset the password so it gets stored in the md5 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many combinations of changing passwords, configs and restarting. Here's what worked:

1. I have removed libpq.so from usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu (libpq.so.5 and libpq.so.5.14 are left alone)
2. Changed all `METHOD`s in `pg_hba.conf` to `trust` & restart postgres
3. Changed `password-encryption` in `postgresql.conf` to `md5` & restart postgres
4. Reset password for user `postgres` (which might have been redundant due to "method/trust") & restart postgres
   ...and it works.

Thank you!